# Find not searching for variable within a loop in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find filenames in a .csv (all in one column) to a directory in a project to determine which files exist in the project. I'm going to output the directories of these files to another csv but can't get find to return anything when using this loop. These files often have underscores, hyphens, and periods but no other special characters or whitespace

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file; do
    echo $file
    find "/Users/myname/Documents/project/software 6.2.0.1/webclient" -name "$file" -exec echo '{}' \;
done < test.csv
```

The `echo $file` runs fine but `find` wont search for it correctly or run my `-exec` commands. It will however run correctly if I substitute `-name "$file"` with `-name "*.ext"`. The find command also runs fine if I just run it in a terminal while the variable is set.

Edits:

Example .csv and script will output same thing to console:

```
Organization_createLocation.uim
Organization_listLocationPopup.properties
Organization_createLocation.properties
Organization_modifyLocationView.properties
Organization_listLocationPopup.uim
Organization_modifyLocationView.vim
```

After running `bash -x ./script.sh` my console reads:

```
+ read file
+ echo $'Organization_createLocation.uim\r'
Organization_createLocation.uim
+ find '/Users/myname/Documents/project/software 6.2.0.1/webclient' -name
$'Organization_createLocation.uim\r' -exec echo '{}' ';'`
```

For every item in the .csv

Comment: What does `echo "$file=="` output? (The quotes are more important, but the `==` makes it obvious if there is a carriage return at the end of the value.)

Comment: Can you post examples of test.csv and the output of your script? Perhaps there's a NL character in $file?

Comment: By the way, `-exec echo '{}'` is somewhat pointless, as it is (intended to be) equivalent to `-print`, which itself is assumed if no other action is provided.

Comment: Running `bash -x yourscript` to enable debug logging would be helpful, as it'll give you the exact `find` commands being run, which you can then compare to working ones.

Comment: ....if this "CSV" file is really being written by a CSV-aware tool, I wouldn't be surprised if the file had literal quotes in it, resulting in `find` looking for names containing quotes (which of course won't be there).

Comment: `dos2unix` the file if it originated at Windows.

Comment: @chepner `echo "$file=="` outputs the name of the file with the first 2 characters replaced by ==, ex: `myfile.txt` will output as `==file.txt`

@CharlesDuffy output comes out

`+ read file
+ echo $'Organization_createLocation.uim\r'
Organization_createLocation.uim`

Looks like it could be a carriage return issue

Comment: @Battlebite That means the value of `file` is something like `foo\r`, not `foo`. You CSV file has DOS line endings, and `bash` treats the `\r` part of the line ending as a regular character.

Answer (score 0):

There were carriage returns on the end of each line. `bash -x ./myscript.sh` helped me find the carriage returns and `dos2unix` solved my issue. It is running fine now.